Не под правами администратора (Windows 10 корпоративная) не могу зайти в свой аккаунт в Microsoft Office
Под правами администратора в Microsoft Office 2019 спокойно захожу в свой аккаунт и могу в классическом приложении открывать файлы из OneDrive, а вот не под правами не могу: кога хочу войти в аккаунт выводится ошибка: "это действие запрещено администратором".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, заранее спасибо!
